# How can I rank my methods?

Tags: ranking

Dears, I designed a game in four different modes and I asked four groups of people to play it and I recorded the amount of time they spend on the game. OK?

Now I want to compare these four modes and decide which mode the best, then which mode, then what, and finally which one the fourth level.

My question is which Statistical test could be used? ANOVA?

Then how can I understand the order of these four modes? What parameter of the test should be considered to order the modes? Sig.? Means Plot?

Comment: There isn't enough here to know how to answer you, or if a statistical solution would be useful.  How do you define a successful game? A test like ANOVA would assume all four modes are equal. If they were indistinguishable from being equal, is that useful knowledge? How many data points per mode do you have? Is there more than one dimension in your definition of success? What impact of who was a player may have impacted the outcome?